# Mount a shared drive as a Volume in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-volume

I have a Linux container which I want to mount a windows file share as a volume when the docker file is debugged using VS 2019

I have the following in my project file, both source and destination folder exist

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-v "Z:\myfolder:/mnt/"</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I run I get the following exception

> 1>docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount
> source path '/host_mnt/uC/10.29.100.22/foldershare/myfolder': mkdir
> /host_mnt/uC: operation not permitted.